# Why does PyCharm not accept my type hint for an empty list?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-typing

What is the correct type hint for `x = []`?

The type checker in my PyCharm editor flagged this as an error:

```
labelframes: List[ttk.LabelFrame] = []
```

`Optional` is not an option as in:

```
labelframes: List[Optional[ttk.LabelFrame]] = []
```

because the documentation for `typing.Optional` states that this is equivalent to:

```
labelframes: List[Union[ttk.LabelFrame, None]] = []
```

and `[None]` is not `[]`.

I ought to mention that PyCharm doesn't like this either:

```
labelframes: List[Union[ttk.LabelFrame, None]] = [None]
```

Whatever type hint I try. PyCharm flags it as an error with,
"Expected to return *<my type hint here>*, got no return," so I tried:

```
labelframes: Optional[List[ttk.LabelFrame, None]] = []
```

That didn't work.

I am aware that PEP 526 has numerous examples which follow the pattern:

```
x: List[str] = []
```

Comment: Does `x: List[str] = []` work in your editor or not?

Comment: @JohnZwinck. I'm not clear what you mean by 'work in my editor'. The type checker of my editor flags this as an error. Type hints are otherwise ignored and have no effect on the operation of Python. Apart from type checking the code performs as if I had written, `labelframes = []`.

Comment: `mypy` doesn't have an issue with it so I'd be confident enough to say that it is probably a bug in Pycharm's typechecker. Couldn't find any relevant issues in their tracker, you might want to report this.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard. I'm not yet comfortable with the idea that this is a PyCharm problem. I went to PEP 484/526 to see if there was a `Null` which could be used in the same manner as `None`. This would enable the following hint:
`labelframes: List[Union[ttk.LabelFrame, Null]] = []`
If there is anything like that I'm not seeing it. That means that there is either a void in the the PEP or (more likely) I'm misunderstanding the PEP. If the PEP has left it undefined then neither PyCharm nor `mypy` are at fault.

Comment: `labelframes: List[ttk.LabelFrame] = []` should already be the correct type hint for an empty list which will eventually contain `ttk.LabelFrame` objects.

Comment: @mkrieger1. I agree. PyCharm's type checker has improved in the six years since this question was posed. Python's typing module was improved roundabout  v3.9  so it's no longer necessary to capitalize `List`. The new syntax is `label frames: list[ttk.LabelFrame]`. PyCharm supports this new syntax.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking at PEP 484, specifically [the section on type comments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments) (the precursor to variable annotations) this does indeed seem like a bug with PyCharm's checker.

Quoting from the PEP:

> In non-stub code, there is a similar special case:
>
> ```
> from typing import IO
>
> stream = None  # type: IO[str]
> ```
>
> Type checkers should not complain about this (despite the value `None` not matching the given type), nor should they change the inferred type to `Optional[...]` (despite the rule that does this for annotated arguments with a default value of None ). The assumption here is that other code will ensure that the variable is given a value of the proper type, and all uses can assume that the variable has the given type.

So, in a similar fashion, type-checkers (as `mypy` currently does), should not complain about the fact that the initializing value you provide doesn't strictly match the annotation.

Comment: `[]` *does* match a `List[ttk.LabelFrame]` annotation, though. The type comment special case only exists because trying to write it like `stream  # type: IO[str]` would raise an error at runtime. It's not supposed to be a general license to initialize variables with values that don't match their type.

Answer (score 6):

Let's first write sample code for an empty list and check it using mypy.

```py
from typing_extensions import reveal_type

l = []
reveal_type(l)
```

Now let's run it in the shell, as below.

```
$ mypy test.py

test.py:4: error: Need type annotation for "l" (hint: "l: List[<type>] = ...")
test.py:6: note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[Any]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Now pay attention to the second line as it says that the type is `List[Any]`.

Lets make changes and re-run

```py
from typing import Any, List
from typing_extensions import reveal_type

l : List[Any] = []

reveal_type(l)
```

And now run mypy.

```
$ mypy test.py

test.py:6: note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[Any]"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: This doesn't mean that `List[Any]` is the "correct" annotation. List literals don't really *have* a definite type - their type is inferred based on the context. If you try `reveal_type([])` directly, you get `builtins.list[<nothing>]`, which would actually be annotated as `list[typing.Never]` rather than `list[typing.Any]`, but `[]` can be inferred as a `list[T]` for any `T` depending on context.