# What's the correct way to type hint an empty list as a literal in python?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a function that always returns an empty list (it's a long story why), I could type hint as usual with just "list", but it would be useful to indicate that the list is always going to be the same.

My first thought was to use literal like this:

```py
from typing import Literal

def get_empty_list() -> Literal[[]]:
    return []
```

Mypy flags this as an invalid type, is there a correct way to type hint an *always empty list*? (obviously, I could type hint just a list, but this is less helpful)

To be explicit, this is a list that is **always empty** and doesn't expect to have any elements. (As seperate for example, from a list that is currently empty, but might have elements of some type added later on).

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264194/what-is-the-correct-type-hint-for-an-empty-list answer your question

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti That's a different issue (that question is not particularly clear)

Comment: This isn't supported by Python's typing system as of today, so depending on how you interface with this empty list, there might be another solution. The most obvious that comes to mind: If "an always empty list" means that you'll never append to it, consider using an empty tuple (`tuple[()]`) instead.

Comment: [typing docs](https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/#illegal-parameters-for-literal-at-type-check-time) state: "Illegal parameters for Literal at type check time: (...) Mutable literal data structures like dict literals, list literals, or set literals: **literals are always implicitly final and immutable**." Your function returning empty list might be a long story, but one that should be resolved instead of finding workarounds for.

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti I'll edit the question to make more clear, but that linked one is around an empty list throwing up problems for static typing, whereas this is a question of how to type something that is an empty list where nothing should be appended to it

Comment: @houseofleft This thing with empty list really is a sign of something improper with the logic, finding a way to factor this out might save you much more troubles later on.

Comment: @matszwecja - I think the question is still valid and there's legitimate use cases for wanting an always empty list. In this example I need to compile a jinja2 template which has list parameters that are irrelevant in the use case- so enforcing them as an empty list seems like a valid and appropriate move?

Comment: Why not pass `[]` or `list` instead? It's then immediately obvious that it is an empty list for everyone reading the code.

Comment: Well, in this specific case its actually and object method's return I wanted to override rather than a direct variable, but I think this is getting a little off topic. My point was more that the question "how do I type hint an always empty list" has a more valid answer than "don't ever do that"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a type that expresses "list that doesn't have elements *now*, but might have elements added later", then that's fundamentally not a static type. Appending elements to such a list would be valid, but would cause the list to stop being an element of that type, which should not happen with static types in a program that respects static typing.

If you want something that expresses "list that has no elements, and will never have elements", you can kind of do it:

```
from typing import Never

def get_empty_list() -> list[Never]:
    return []
```

Here, we've annotated the element type as `typing.Never`, a type with no values. This is actually the type mypy infers for an empty list literal if there's no context to suggest another type, as [you can see](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=055f2691f72c21d152ba6ec43c6e9003) with `reveal_type`:

```
from typing import Never

x: list[Never]
reveal_type(x)
reveal_type([])
```

mypy output:

```
main.py:4: note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[<nothing>]"
main.py:5: note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[<nothing>]"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Here are the implications of using a `list[Never]` type:

- Static type checkers will not allow operations that add elements to a list annotated as `list[Never]`.
- They *will* allow operations like `get_empty_list().append(sys.exit())`, where the argument to `append` is an expression that cannot evaluate to a value.
- They will recognize that `get_empty_list()[0]` cannot evaluate to a value... but this is very different from considering it a prohibited operation. In fact, rather than prohibiting the operation, they will *allow* it, in almost any context.

  After all, if an expression cannot produce a value, then it cannot produce a value of the wrong type, no matter what the *right* type is. So you can do stuff like

  ```
  x: int = get_empty_list()[0]
  ```

  and from a static typing perspective, that's perfectly valid. (`[][0]` is [considered valid too](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=7528d2ee3ef5a9d2cc06c467d67f56f7).)
- They will *not* recognize that `len(get_empty_list())` must be 0.

Answer (score -3):

```py
from typing import List

def get_empty_list() -> List:
    return []

result = get_empty_list()
print(result)  # Output: []
```

The List annotation without any type parameters is used to indicate that the function returns a list, but it doesn't specify the type of elements in the list.

Comment: "it doesn't specify the type of elements in the list" - and that's why it doesn't answer the question asked.